# How to loop multiple form fields in a table then submit

Tags: python, django

Ideally i am working on attendance of members, On a given date, members who have attended are roll called, then their status submitted at once in the attendance table.
[image: here is the image of the table] 
here is my code
**views.py**

```
def make_attendence(request):
if request.method=="POST":
    form=AttendanceForm(request.POST, request.FILES,)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        messages.success(request, f'Members Attendance For Today has been Made')
        return redirect('attendence-history')
else:
    form=AttendanceForm()
    all_members=CustomUser.objects.all()
    context={'form':form, 'all_members':all_members}
    return render(request,'make_attendance.html',context)
```

**make_attendance.html**

```
    <form  method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
                                {% csrf_token %}
                {% load crispy_forms_tags %}

            <table id="data-table" class="table table-striped table-bordered dt-responsive nowrap" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
              <div class="col-lg-4 form-group">
                  <label for="date">Date:</label>
                  <input type="date" name="date" class="form-control" id="date" required="*" >
              </div>
                <thead>
                  <tr style="font-weight: bolder;">
                    <td>Name</td>
                    <td>Attendance</td>
                    <td>Social fund</td>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                  {% for member in all_members %}

                    <tr>
                        <td>{{member.full_name}}<input type="hidden" id="full_name" name="full_name" value="{{member.full_name}}"></td>
                        <td>{{form.status}}</td>
                        <td>{{form.social_fund}}</td>
                    </tr>

                    {% endfor %}
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" >Submit</button>
        </form>
```

The problem am facing is that on submit, only one record is saved in the attendance table.
Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After going through django docs, i was able to grasp concept of Create()
This method works well for Postgresql but not with sqlite database as it won't create Pks

In the template you have to pass the name in the input which will be called in views
**attendance.html**

```
 <table id="data-table" class="table table-striped table-bordered dt-responsive nowrap" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
           <div class="col-lg-4 form-group">
               <label for="date">Date:</label>
               <input type="date" name="date" class="form-control" id="date" required="*" >
           </div>
             <thead>
               <tr style="font-weight: bolder;">
                <td>id</td>
                 <td>Name</td>
                 <td>Present?</td>
               </tr>
             </thead>
             <tbody>
               {% for member in all_members %}
               {% if member.first_name != None and member.last_name != None %}
                 <tr> <td>{{member.id}}</td>
                     <td>{{member.full_name}}
                     </td>
                     <td><input type="checkbox" id="{{member.id}}" name="status" value="{{member.id}}"></td>
                 </tr>
                 {% endif %}
                 {% endfor %}
             </tbody>
         </table>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" >Submit</button>
        </form>
```

In the views get the name passed from the template as a list, then loop through to get each item that you want to create at a single submit button hit.

**views.py**

```
def make_attendence(request):
current_cycle = Cycle.objects.get(is_active=True)
if request.method == 'POST':
    todate = request.POST.get('date')
    tostate = request.POST.getlist('status')
    for i in tostate:
        status_id = i
        member_id=CustomUser.objects.filter(id=status_id)
        for j in member_id:
            tostatus='Present'
            tofullname = str(j.first_name )+ " " + str(j.last_name)
            Attendance.objects.create(date=todate, status=tostatus, full_name=tofullname)
    messages.success(request, f'Attendance has been succefully recorded')
    return redirect('attendence-history')
all_members = CustomUser.objects.all()
context={'all_members':all_members, 'current_cycle':current_cycle}
return render(request,'make_attendance.html',context)
```